# NodeJS - infinite call on promise functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, promise, setinterval

I'm looking for a way to call infinitely a functions with promises. 
I tried 2 scenarios, one works the other don't.
The aim of the code that doesn't works is to: get data from an API and then store it into a database.

I'm learning promises, can someone explain me why one is working and the other don't ?
Below my codes

**Working code**
The function is called only once, I'm looking to get it called infinitly

```
const request = require('request') //node to facilitate http request
var nano    = require('nano')('http://admin:12345@localhost:5984'); //connect to couchdb using id and password
var db_name  = nano.db.use('bitfinex'); //couchdb database name
var ltc_url = 'https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/ltcusd' //entry point
var nonce = new Date().toISOString()  //gives a unique id
                      .replace(/T/, ' ')    // replace T with a space
                      .replace(/\..+/, '')     // delete the dot and everything after

let cleanTheRoom = function() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve('Cleaned the Room, ');
      });
    };

  let removedTheGarbage = function(msg) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      resolve(msg + 'removed the garbage, ');
    });
  };

  let getIcecream = function(msg) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      resolve(msg +'got icecream.');
    });
  };

setInterval(function(){
  cleanTheRoom()
    .then(removedTheGarbage)
    .then(getIcecream)
    .then(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg );
  });
}, 2000);
```

**Failing code**

```
const request = require('request') //node to facilitate http request
    var nano    = require('nano')('http://admin:12345@localhost:5984'); //connect to couchdb using id and password
    var db_name  = nano.db.use('bitfinex'); //couchdb database name
    var ltc_url = 'https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/ltcusd' //entry point
    var nonce = new Date().toISOString()  //gives a unique id
                          .replace(/T/, ' ')    // replace T with a space
                          .replace(/\..+/, '')     // delete the dot and everything after

// get current litecoin price from Bitfinex

function getLtcPrice(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    request.get(ltc_url,
        function (error, response, body) {
        var rep = JSON.parse(body);
        var ltc_price = rep.ask;
          resolve (ltc_price)
        if (error){
          reject(ltc_price)
          }
      });
    })
  }

//save current litecoin price to the database

function saveLtcPrice (ltc_price){
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve(
        db_name.insert({ _id: nonce, currency:"Litecoin", price: ltc_price},
           function(err, body) {
             if (!err)
             console.log(" ltc price : "+ ltc_price +", uploaded to the database ");
          })
          )
      });
    }

setInterval(function(){
  getLtcPrice()
    .then(function(ltcPrice){
      saveLtcPrice(ltcPrice);
    });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: what error messages are you getting. Can you give a bit more info?

Comment: What if a previous call wasn't finished yet when the handler for setInterval is triggered again? Should it wait for the previous request(s) to finish?

Comment: @ZombieChowder : I actually don't get any error message, it's just that it run only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your saveLtcPrice to resolve after the insert was done:

```
// get current litecoin price from Bitfinex
function getLtcPrice(){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
       request.get(ltc_url, function (error, response, body) {
           if (error) reject(error)

           var rep = JSON.parse(body);
           var ltc_price = rep.ask;
           resolve (ltc_price)
       });
   })
}

//save current litecoin price to the database
function saveLtcPrice (ltc_price){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        db_name.insert({
            _id: nonce,
            currency:"Litecoin",
            price: ltc_price
        }, function(error, body) {
            if(error) reject(error)

            console.log(" ltc price : "+ ltc_price +", uploaded to the database ");
            resolve(body)
      })
  });
}

Promise.resolve().then(function resolver() {
    return getLtcPrice().then(function(ltcPrice){
        return saveLtcPrice(ltcPrice);
    }).then(resolver)// both functions ended, call them again
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
});
```

Comment: I believe a recursive function without using setTimeout or setImmediate will lead to a `stack overflow`.  I may be wrong if its wrapped in a promise I am curious now.

Comment: @JohnRodney: This won’t lead to a stack overflow. `.then(resolver)` schedules `resolver` to be run later and the current `resolver`’s stack frame isn’t needed anymore. See also the typical usage of `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: @Ryan this comment was placed on a older version of this answer, where I did a recursive function that called itself after promises were resolved, which indeed leaded to stack overflow

Comment: @Valera: I don’t think it would have

Comment: That work nice! :) thanks a lot guys for your help. I still need to practive the promises to fully understand how it should be set up properl

Answer (score 1):

i see 2 errors in your falling code. In getLtcPrice function, you should check for errors before resolving, so.

```
function getLtcPrice(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    request.get(ltc_url, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) { // check for errors immediatly
        reject(ltc_price)
        return
      }
        var rep = JSON.parse(body);
        var ltc_price = rep.ask;
        resolve(ltc_price)
      });
    })
  }
```

in saveLtcPrice function, you are always resolving passing a call to an async function. This make no sense. You should do exactly like you did in getLtcPrice function, so:

```
function saveLtcPrice (ltc_price) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        db_name.insert({ _id: nonce, currency:"Litecoin", price: 
          ltc_price},function(err, document) { //changed variable name "body" to "document". it's just a convention, this is not the body of an http request, this is an object inside a database
             if (err) {
               reject(err)
               return
             }

             console.log(" ltc price : "+ ltc_price +", uploaded to the database ");
             resolve(document)
          })
          )
      });
    }
```

Finally, you should catch errors inside your setInterval function

Comment: You still have `getLtcPrice` wrong: you need an `else` so that only one branch gets called: if there is an error there is probably no body to parse.

Comment: @Duncan not true. if you reject inside a promise, code execution is immediatly halted.

Comment: that's not what any documentation says, nor is it what the built-in Promise implementation does. Try in your browser console: `new Promise(function(resolve,reject) { reject('rejected'); console.log('foo'); })` it will output `foo` as well as rejecting the promise.

Comment: reject doesn't halt but once rejected; calling resolve doesn't do anything. Throwing an error will just return a rejected promise as well so no problem (won't reject multiple times either). Note that when you use Promise polyfil anything can happen so it is best to return after calling resolve or reject `reject(err);return;`

Comment: Yes @HMR, so what would happen here is that the promise is rejected then the code throws an error when `JSON.parse(body)` fails but the error is simply ignored.

Comment: yes, try it `new Promise( (a,r)=>{ r("nope"); a("ok"); console.log("still running though");throw "wut"; } ) .then( x=>console.log("resolved:",x) ,y=>console.warn("rejected",y) )`

Comment: @Duncan An exception from `JSON.parse` is *not* simply ignored, it's a globally uncaught exception and will terminate your process.

Comment: @Bergi, it's an exception thrown from inside the `Promise` executor, so it is not uncaught: it is caught and handled by the `Promise` constructor. If it happens before the Promise is rejected it will reject the Promise. If it happens when the Promise is already rejected it will still attempt to reject the Promise but nothing will happen.

Comment: @Duncan No! It's an exception thrown inside the `request.get` callback, the promise constructor has nothing to do with this. Actually one should write `new Promise((resolve, reject) => request.get(… resolve(body) …)).then(JSON.parse)` because of this

Comment: @Bergi, oh yes you're correct. In that case the exception will be logged as uncaught. Still they should be returning after calling `reject()`.

Comment: @Duncan That's without question, yes :-) I personally favour `if (err) reject(err) else resolve(res)`

Answer (score 0):

Your saveLtcPrice function has a very weird placement of the call to `resolve`

```
function saveLtcPrice (ltc_price){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    resolve( /* <--- HERE */
    db_name.insert({ _id: nonce, currency:"Litecoin", price: ltc_price},
       function(err, body) {
         if (!err)
         console.log(" ltc price : "+ ltc_price +", uploaded to the database ");
      })
      )
  });
}
```

Maybe you should call the resolve after the database operation has finished in the final callback.

```
function saveLtcPrice (ltc_price){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    db_name.insert({ _id: nonce, currency:"Litecoin", price: ltc_price},
       function(err, body) {
         if (!err) {
           resolve(body) /* <-- Move to here */
           console.log(" ltc price : "+ ltc_price +", uploaded to the database ");
         } else {
           reject(err);
         }
       })
  });
}
```

What it appears is that you attempt to resolve with a call to a database async operation.  Since this database operation accepts a callback as a parameter it is very unlikely your promise is resolved with anything other than `undefined`.

Make sure you handle your promise rejects correctly and try to use `.catch()` so that you can catch your errors otherwise locating the source of code problems in promises can be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Adding one more answer:

```
// get current litecoin price from Bitfinex
const getLtcPrice = (ltc_url) =>
  new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) =>
      request.get(
        ltc_url,
        (error, response, body) =>
          error
            ? reject(error)
            : resolve(JSON.parse(body).ask)
      )
  );

//save current litecoin price to the database
const saveLtcPrice = (ltc_price) =>
  new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) =>
      db_name.insert(
        { _id: nonce, currency: "Litecoin", price: ltc_price },
        (err, body) =>
          err
            ? reject(err)
            : console.log(" ltc price : " + ltc_price + ", uploaded to the database ")
              || resolve(body)
    )
  );

const keepGettingPrice = () => {
  const rec =
    p =>
      //if previous saves were not finished then wait for it to finish
      p = p.then(
        //!!!!!!!!!!!!! where does ltc_url come from?
        _ => getLtcPrice(ltc_url)
      ).then(
        saveLtcPrice
      ).then(
        undefined,
        //handle the error
        err=>console.warn("failed one:",err,)
      )
      .then(
        x=>new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(r,2000))
      );
  return rec(Promise.resolve());
};
keepGettingPrice();
```

Comment: Would you please use a proper `if` statement with blocks for side effects? `console.log(…) &&` doesn't even work.

Comment: @Bergi Yea, forgot console.log returns undefined. Usually just squeeze them in like this for debugging so I don't need to add `{}` for the function.